# How can I update DOM with an event object

Tags: javascript, dom

I have `innerDOM` of my page captured and posted to my serverside program for every page load.

```
innerDom=document.body.innerHTML;
```

I am able to get the event obect which contains details about every click from the below function defenition:

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt)
```

Here `evt` also is posted back to server side.

I am trying to recreate my page in another browser using the innerdom and evt object with every user interaction recreated.

Is this possible? if so how can I render the page with inner `DOM` and `evt` object?

Any pointers will be really appreciated.